# What is that system command return?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, system

I have a module like this. First of all i'm wanna explain all `logger($arg1,$arg2)` puts output on console it is just created for that. And the parameters $source_server,@source_user,@log_name_pattern,@log_name_pattern,@archive_interval,@move_interval are read from .csv file there is no problem with them.

```
use constant OUTPUT_PATH => "./outputs/";
use constant MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH => 100000;
my $cmd_bash = "bash";
my $cmd_source = "source .profile";
sub run_remote_command_with_login
{
    my $start_time = time;
    my $host = shift;
    my $cmd = shift;
    my $user = shift;
    my $pwd = shift;
    my $is_import = 1 if (shift);

    if(length($cmd) > MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH)
    {
        logger(ERROR, "The command will not be run as it is longer than ".MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH." characters");
        return 0;
    }


    logger(DEBUG, "Opening telnet for ".$host." with user $user");

    $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => TIMEOUT, Errmode => ERRORMODE, Prompt => '/([>\$%~]|Logging out)\s*$/');
    $t->open($host);

    unless($t->login($user, $pwd)){
        logger(WARNING, "Login failed with return value $response");
        logger(WARNING, "Login failed to $host with user $user");
        return "";
    }
    $t->max_buffer_length(BUFFER);

    my @lines = $t->cmd($cmd_bash);
    @lines = $t->cmd($cmd_source);

    logger(DEBUG, "Running command: ".$cmd);

    if ($is_import)
    {
        $t->print($cmd);
        ($prematch, $match) = $t->waitfor('/.*Logging out.*/i');
        @lines = split(/\n/, $prematch);
        $ok = $t->close;
    }
    else
    {
        @lines = $t->cmd($cmd);
        $ok = $t->close;
    }   

    if($ok)
    {
        logger(DEBUG, "Closed telnet for ".$host);
    }
    else
    {
        logger(WARNING, "Could not close telnet for ".$host);
        logger(WARNING, "Error code: ".$ok);
    }

    logger(DEBUG, "Output lines are:"); 
    for($i = 0; $i < scalar(@lines); $i++)
    {
        logger(DEBUG, $lines[$i]);
    }
    logger(DEBUG, "End of output lines.");

    if (not -d OUTPUT_PATH)
    {
        my $cmd = "mkdir ".OUTPUT_PATH;
        `$cmd`;
    }
    my $out = OUTPUT_PATH.$start_time.".txt";
    open(DAT2, ">$out") || die("Could not open file!");
    logger(INFO, "Remote command execution finished in ".(time - $start_time)." seconds. (Output: $out)");

    for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@lines); $i++)
    {
        print DAT2 $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    close(DAT2);

    return \@lines;
}
```

This module is written for Telnet connection to remote server and it works fine. But we have some linux servers and they wanted me to connect these servers via SSH. İt's not problem but in that remote hoste we wanted to archive or move files. We have modules like this in Archive.pl :

```
sub archive
{
    my $cmd_list = "find $source_dir -name \"$log_name_pattern\" -a ! -name \"*.gz\" -a ! -mtime -$archive_interval -a ! -size 0 -a -type f";
    my $cmd_gzip = "find $source_dir -name \"$log_name_pattern\" -a ! -name \"*.gz\" -a ! -mtime -$archive_interval -a ! -size 0 -a -type f -exec gzip {} \\;";

    Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command: $cmd_list");

    my $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($source_server, $cmd_list, $source_user, get_pwd($source_user));

    extract_files(\@$output);

    if(scalar(@$output) == 0)
    {
        Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"No files found to archive.");
    }
    else
    {
        Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO, scalar(@$output)." file(s) will be zipped:");
        for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@$output); $i++)
        {
            print $$output[$i];
        }   

        Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command: $cmd_gzip");
        if($source_user == "picshot"){
            $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($source_server, $cmd_gzip, $source_user, get_pwd($source_user));
        }
        else{
            $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($source_server, $cmd_gzip, $source_user, get_pwd($source_user));
        }
    }
}

sub move
{   
    my $cmd_filelist = "find $source_dir -name \"$log_name_pattern.gz\" -a ! -mtime -$move_interval -a -type f";
    Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command: $cmd_filelist");
    my $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($source_server, $cmd_filelist, $source_user, get_pwd($source_user));

    extract_files(\@$output);

    if(scalar(@$output) == 0)
    {
        Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"No files found to move");
    }
    else
    {
        Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO, scalar(@$output)." file(s) will be moved:");
        for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@$output); $i++)
        {
            print $$output[$i];
        }   

        if($source_server ne $target_server)
        {
            my $to_delete = Utilities::run_remote_ftp($source_server, $source_dir, $source_user, $source_user, $target_server, $target_dir, $target_user, $target_user, $output);

            if(scalar(@$to_delete) == 0)
            {
                Utilities::logger(Utilities::WARNING,"FTP put returned no files, keeping source files");
            }
            else
            {
                Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"FTP put finished. Removing files returned by PUT");
                my $cmd_delete = "rm ";

                for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@$to_delete); $i++)
                {
                    $$to_delete[$i] = Utilities::trim($$to_delete[$i]);
                    $cmd_delete = $cmd_delete.$$to_delete[$i]." ";
                }
                Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command: $cmd_delete");
                Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($source_server, $cmd_delete, $source_user, get_pwd($source_user));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            my $cmd_move = "mv ";
            for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@$output); $i++)
            {
                $$output[$i] = Utilities::trim($$output[$i]);
                $cmd_move = $cmd_move." ".$$output[$i];
            }
            $cmd_move = $cmd_move." ".$target_dir;

            # Create target dir if it does not exist.
            my $cmd_create_dir = "mkdir -p ".$target_dir;
            Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command: $cmd_create_dir");
            my $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($target_server, $cmd_create_dir, $target_user, get_pwd($target_user));

            Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command to move files");
            Utilities::logger(Utilities::INFO,"Running command: $cmd_move");
            $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($target_server, $cmd_move, $target_user, get_pwd($target_user));
            Utilities::check_move_cmd($output);
        }
    }
}
```

These two modules are working fine. They are succesfully archiving and moving files.

I did ssh-keygen it rsa configuration between the servers which i want to connect. I'm trying to run this on the perl script :

```
my $cmd_gzip = "$source_dir -name \"$log_name_pattern\" -a ! -name \"*.gz\" -a ! -mtime -$archive_interval -a ! -size 0 -a -type f -exec gzip {} \\;";

system("ssh", "$source_user\@$source_server" , "find" , $cmd_gzip);
```

It succesfully connects to remote server, listing the files. But when i wanted to zip the files i wanted to archive it doesn't work. Console says "Permission denied"

Archive module which is at the top has extract_files module. It is like this :

```
sub extract_files
{
    Utilities::logger(Utilities::DEBUG,"Entering sub: extract_files");
    my $temp = shift;

    my $size = scalar(@$temp);
    Utilities::logger(Utilities::DEBUG,"Initial array size is $size.");
    my $temp_log_name_pattern = $log_name_pattern;
    $temp_log_name_pattern =~ s/\*/.*/g;

    my $i = 0;
    while($i < $size)
    {
        Utilities::logger(Utilities::DEBUG,"Currently processing: $$temp[$i]. i = $i, size = $size");
        # Extract only files from output. " character in second part is used to filter out initial find command that can wrap and exist in the output.
        if ($$temp[$i] =~ $temp_log_name_pattern and $$temp[$i] !~ m/.*".*/)
        {
            Utilities::logger(Utilities::DEBUG,"Matched filename: $$temp[$i]");
            $i++;
        }
        else
        {
            Utilities::logger(Utilities::DEBUG,"Did not match filename: $$temp[$i]");
            splice(@$temp,$i,1);
            $size--;
        }
    }
    Utilities::logger(Utilities::DEBUG,"Exiting sub: extract_files");
}
```

I think this makes the Script work and avoids from Error "Permission denied". But it gets a parameter like this :

```
my $output = Utilities::run_remote_command_with_login($source_server, $cmd_list, $source_user, get_pwd($source_user));

    extract_files(\@$output);
```

So now I'm asking two things,

1. I didn't get that what this run_remote_command_with_login module return so i can not create my ssh connection module to use all modules correctly. How can i get a return from my system command ? like run_remote_command_with_login module got `system("ssh", "$source_user\@$source_server" , "find" , $cmd_gzip);`(I didn't write that module)
2. If I'm wrong extract_files() module doesn't work for avoiding "Permission denied" error. How can i do it ? Is there any ideas.

I hope that I told everything i want to ask truely. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that the user account for the ZIPping has the right permissions. You may need to print out the user account, which under Linux can be done with the `id` command.